# When does an Area 51 beta begin?

Tags: discussion, area-51

What is the trigger to move an Area 51 proposal from commitment-phase to beta-phase? Or perhaps better phrased as, How long after 100% commitment is reached does the beta begin?

Comment: Its just a matter of the hamsters generating 1.21 gigawatts, that sometimes takes a bit of time.

Comment: Does that mean that Area51 is more "eco-green" than Google? Excellent!

Comment: @rib.usa - sadly, the hamsters are outsourced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fairly manual at the moment.

It also depends how much commitment overlap there is between sites, in other words, how many people committed to *both* A and B and C? If the overlap is low between A and C then we may launch those first, and wait on B.

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but I won't pretend it is to me: *If the overlap is low between A and C then we may launch those first, and wait on B.* Please explain that a bit more why you do this.

Answer (score 2):

It's a manual process.

It depends on how many betas the team can handle, there isn't an exact formula, but approximately 3 per week now, in order of progress.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's being handled on a case-by-case basis now, as soon as they have the resources to start another beta, but I don't have an actual source for that

Answer (score 0):

Jeff - I think it was Jeff - wrote a while ago that the 100% committed sites are being put in beta one at a time, so the admins can pace the system and ensure nothing breaks. Otherwise it would be a crazy free-for-all.

Comment: This is correct. Right now they are done one by one because Area51 is still in Beta itself.