# How long does a site stay in 'committed at 100%' before it's launched?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When does an Area 51 beta begin?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58090/when-does-an-area-51-beta-begin)

[A site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2732/atheism) I'm committed to has been at 100% commitment for a full day. I'm just wondering when it'll be launched?

Comment: Hope they won't delay its launch to wait for the jewish site to reach 100% commitment first :P